# Flutter Firestore can't find provider in the widget tree?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I am trying to firebase in my app and I keep running into problems. I've tried the suggestions in this screen shot, but I think perhaps I am not understanding properly. [image: output from flutter run]

Its saying cannot find correct Provider, I am guessing it can't find it in the tree. But it looks to me as if it is there
[image: where my provider is]

Here is my main where I call provider
[image]

Comment: How did you implemented the provider part can you show me the code ?

Comment: in main I did this:


***`Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: FirebaseOptions(
      apiKey: configurations.apiKey,
      appId: configurations.appId,
      messagingSenderId: configurations.messagingSenderId,
      projectId: configurations.projectId,
    ),
  );
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [Provider(create: (_) => CategoryService())],
      child: Setup(),
    ),
  );
}`***

Comment: First of all implement some page (let it be Homepage) as MaterialApp then inside that MaterialApp implement your MultiProvider widget .

Answer (score 0):

So it turns out this is what works. Now i just need to figure out how to present the data.

[image: This now runs and fixes the issue]

Comment: It works @Julia Pak ?